# jquery .on() not working after .load() of php file

Tags: ajax, jquery

I'm attempting to run the following simple bit of code on an html snippet contained in a php file, loaded with jquery's .load() function:

```
$(".thumbnail").on("click", function(event){

    alert("thumbnail clicked");
});
```

However, I can't seem to get it to work on this portion of my page. I have other calls to elements not loaded via ajax and they work fine with the .on() function. I was under the impression that .on() would recognize ajax loaded content.

My .thumbnail elements are pictures in img tags contained within a series of divs all loaded via ajax, jquery can't seem to find any of this content. All of my code is contained within the ready function.

Is there a way to get jquery to recognize these new elements?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a delegated event handler for dynamic content :

```
$('#container').load('somefile.php');

$('#container').on('click', '.thumbnail', function(event){
     // do stuff
});
```

The closest non-dynamic parent would probably be the element you're loading the content into, and you need to attach the event handler to that element, filtering based on the `.thumbnail` class, like the code above.